# Access dictionary module items

Tags: python, dictionary

my working folder is /scripts/

I created a file that contains only a dictionary

```
my_dict = {'sky' : 'blue'}
```

Within that file, I can `print my_dict['sky']` just fine.

In PyCharm I created a new folder within /scripts/ called /scripts/dictionaries/. Inside there I have a file called dictionary_file.py, inside of which is my_dict.

It seems PyCharm auto generated a dictionaries module. I can `from dictionaries import my_dict` fine but then why I try to do my_dict['sky'] I get:

```
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm sure this is a dumb noob question, but I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Please show the file/directory structure of your module (i.e., what the file containing this code is called, and what the directory containing it is called, and whether these are on `sys.path`).  It sounds like you actually have a package with a module inside it.

Comment: This isn't a directory structure issue. Use import dictionaries and then do dictionaries.myDict['sky']

Comment: By importing myDict from dictionaries, python thinks that myDict is a module of a package called dictionaries

Comment: I've updated my OP. Sorry for not including more detail and the folder structure.

Comment: Read my comments, it gives the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from dictionaries.dictionary_file import myDict

print myDict['sky']
```

will for sure throw: `TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` because Python thinks that myDict is a `module` object in this case

```
from dictionaries import dictionary_file

print dictionary_file.myDict['sky']
```

Now Python knows that the module dictionary_file of the package dictionaries has something called myDict and discovers on runtime that myDict is a `dict` which has a `__getitem__` method implemented.

Anytime you try to access a dictionary value via its key, python called the `__getitem__` method of the `dict` class.

You can also do

```
from dictionaries.dictionary_file import *

print myDict['sky']
```

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally seemed to have deleted the import part when I edited my OP for clarification. Your original answer which amounted to `modulename.dictname[key]` worked just fine. Thanks for your help.